# Cleaning up leaves in a rock landscaped garden

Tags: ground-cover, rock-gardening

After a few great years, my garden, which is landscaped with medium size rocks has lost some of it's shine.  The, originally, white rocks are now off colored and the leaves are piling up thick under the bushes and herbs.

Is there a trick to cleaning up the leaves and restoring some of the brightness to the rocks?

Comment: do you have a picture of what we are dealing with here? Also what kind of rocks?

Comment: A leaf blower sounds like an option. Your neighbors will hate you, though.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/2132/109

Answer (score 3):

I would guess you just want these leaves there to stay and keep your soil covered. It protects the soil and it keeps the soil moist.

One figures why the leaves aren't composting quick enough. In nature, nobody blows the leaves away and look how green and shiny most plants and trees look.

I suggest to have a look if there are enough critters, worms, beetles etc. in the soil.

If a plant looses shine and turns yellow, it lacks nitrogen. Applying bloodmeal will help getting the nitrogen back into the soil.

Comment: If there are a layer of rocks between the leaves and the bugs they are not going to feast on the leaves as easily.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your problem is a leaf blower and pressure cleaner. The blower will move the loose stuff and the pressure cleaner will turn the rocks pearly white.

That is the get it clean at any cost method. If you ask the permaculturist in me... It sounds like you are already getting some natural mulch which is going to break down and feed your plants naturally. Shift the rocks to an area to make a water catchment, then you will have free mulch + water.

Note: Leaves piling up under bushes = good for the bushes!